# Access to JQuery element - $.data

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get access to JQuery element.

I create element:

```
var el = $('<div></div>');

$.data(el, 'data', {first: 'first'});

$('body').append(el);
```

I can read the data:

```
$.data(el, 'data').first
```

But I need read by HTML tag or class:

```
$.data('div', 'data').first
```

Is it possible?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hesnvo72/1/)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all be careful how you are using the [jQuery.data](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) function because it is a low-level method. It is not designed to be used with jQuery elements but raw DOM elements. According to the [jQuery.data( element, key, value )](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/#jQuery-data-element-key-value), `element` expects a ***DOM*** element to associate with the data. I emphasize the DOM because you are passing a jQuery instead of the corresponding DOM element to `$.data`:

```
var el = $('<div></div>');
$.data(el, 'data', {first: 'first'});
```

You should pass the actual DOM element instead:

```
$.data(el[0], 'data', {first: 'first'})
```

Then you'll be able to recover the `data` field in several ways:

```
// Using the jQuery.data method.
$.data(el[0], 'data').first
$.data($('div')[0], 'data').first

// Using the more convenient contextual method .data
el.data('data').first
$('div').data('data').first

// Combining jQuery and vanilla js
$.data(document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0], 'data').first
```

But, how is the statement below getting the proper stored data attribute?

```
$.data(el, 'data').first
```

As you are calling the `jQuery.data` with a jQuery element you are adding the `data` attribute to the jQuery wrapper element, not the wrapped DOM element. So the only way to retrieve this `data` field is using the same object:

```
$.data(el, 'data').first
el.data('data').first
```

But, once the `el` reference is gone, you are not going to be able to recover your `data` attribute again. Because as I said before, you are not storing this `data` attribute in the DOM model but in a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you correctly, use the data API on the jQuery object itself:

```
$('div').first().data()
```

Comment: Well, that is the data object. Not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It is not working because the `data` attribute has not been added to the div DOM element. Otherwise, it would get the proper data object of the first div element.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the end goal, I would either just save the variable in your javascript, or add an additional data attribute to your div to easily select later.

so you could do

```
$('<div />', { 'data-has-data': 'true' }).data({ first: 'first' }).appendTo('body');
```

and then you can later do

```
$('div[data-has-data]').data().first
```

or you could do

```
var el = $('<div />').data({ first: 'first' }).appendTo('body');

// to access later
var firstData = el.data().first;
```

Comment: Yes, I wrote about later access by variable but I need by HTML tags or classes. Because I have many elements. And I need read the data from `.active` class. And I use `$.data`, not `el.data()`. `$.data` is more quickly.